# Find the probability that a word with 15 letters (selected from P,T,I,N) does not contain TINT

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

If a word with 15 letters is formed at random using the letters P, T, I, N,

find the probability that it does not contain the sequence TINT.

(I just made up this problem.)

Comment: I suppose "at random" means that the 15 letters are independently and uniformly chosen from $P, T, I, N$? In that case the probability would be equal to the number of possible 15-letter words not containing $TINT$ divided by the number of possible 15-letter words, right?

Comment: Possibly $\dfrac{1024574807}{1073741824}\approx0.9542$, not far away from  $1-\dfrac{12}{4^4}=0.953125$, where $\dfrac{12}{4^4}$ is the expected number of appearances of "TINT"

Comment: do you mean exactly one sequence TINT or any number?

Comment: 1024574807 / (4^15) is correct.

Comment: How are the both of you @Henry and @ Steve D, calculating the number 1024574807?  Brute force computer code?  Inclusion exclusion?  Recurrence formula?  Some other (*perhaps easier*) method than those I mention?

Comment: Recurrence for me.  Incidentally, I think the expected number of letters until "TINT" first appears may be $4^4+4 = 260$ and $1-\dfrac{12}{260}\approx  0.9538$ is a better approximation

Comment: @McFry Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @Alex I mean that it does not contain any number of the sequences TINT.

Comment: @MontyHall your question title says *contains*.  Your body says *does not contain*, hence the ambiguity.  The one probability is directly related to the other via $Pr(A)=1-Pr(A^c)$.  I.e. the two probabilities should add up to be equal to one, so the question of finding the one answer is equivalent to the question of finding the other answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm sorry, and thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why $1 - \frac{12}{4^4}$ is wrong? I am getting that answer.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 presumably, you calculated that by 1: picking the location of the beginning of the word "TINT" 2: Finding the probability that that location does indeed contain the word "TINT".  Although $\frac{1}{4^4}$ is the probability that spaces $i,i+1,i+2,i+3$ contain the letters TINT, the outcomes themselves *overlap* and are not mutually exclusive, hence you may not simply add the probabilities together as you have.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I believe this answer is a slight simplification of the first answer, where we use the fact that we don't need to keep track of words that do contain TINT when we're trying to see how an $n+1$-letter word not containing TINT can be obtained from an $n$-letter one.

Let $a_n$ be the number of $n$-letter words not containing TINT and ending with TIN. Let $b_n$ be the number of $n$-letter words not containing TINT and ending with TI. And let $c_n$ be the number of $n$-letter words not containing TINT ending with T. Finally let $d_n$ be the number of $n$-letter words not containing TINT that don't fall in any of the above categories. Then we have
\begin{align*}
 a_n = b_{n-1}, \quad b_n = c_{n-1}, \quad c_n = b_{n-1} + c_{n-1} + d_{n-1} 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 d_n = 3a_{n-1} + 2b_{n-1} + 2c_{n-1} + 3d_{n-1}
\end{align*}
So if we have the column vector $(a_{n-1},b_{n-1},c_{n-1},d_{n-1})^T$, the column vector of the new guys $(a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n)^T$ is obtained by multiplying on the left by the matrix
\begin{align*}
A=
 \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 3 & 2 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
For $n=1$, the vector is $v=(0,0,1,3)^T$. So we need to compute the sum of the entries of $A^{14}v$, which gives us the answer others have already given in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Let's name our alphabet $A := \{P, T, I, N\}$.

Let's look at the set $L := A^*$ of all possible words using the letters $P, T, I, N$. First, let's dissect it into five sets:

$$L_5 := \{w \in L : TINT\text{ is a substring of }w\},$$
$$L_4 := \{w \in L \smallsetminus L_5 : w\text{ ends with } TIN\},$$
$$L_3 := \{w \in L \smallsetminus L_5 : w\text{ ends with } TI\},$$
$$L_2 := \{w \in L \smallsetminus L_5 : w\text{ ends with } T\},$$
$$L_1 := L \setminus (L_1 \cup L_2 \cup L_3 \cup L_4).$$

Example: The word $PTTPTIN$ would be in $L_4$.

The nice thing about our five sets $L_1, \ldots, L_5$ is that for any $a \in A$, $w \in L_i$, the class $L_j \ni wa$ is completely determined by $i$ and $a$. For example: If $w \in L_3$, then $wN$ is always in $L_4$.

We give each state a corresponding state vector $$s_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0 \\0 \\0 \\0\end{pmatrix}, s_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1 \\0 \\0 \\0\end{pmatrix}, s_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0 \\1 \\0 \\0\end{pmatrix}, s_4=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0 \\0 \\1 \\0\end{pmatrix}, s_5=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0 \\0 \\0 \\1\end{pmatrix}$$

and denote by $s(w)$ the state vector of the state $w$ is in. For example $s(TPTI) = s_3$.

Suppose now we have a random word $W$ over $L$. We can describe the expected state of $W$ by $S(W) := \mathbb{E}(s(W))$, which is a convex combination of the state vectors, a vector whose $i$-th entry denotes the probability of $W$ being in $L_i$. Now suppose $l$ is a random letter independent from $W$, uniformly chosen from $A$.

Then $S(Wl) = B \cdot S(W)$, where

$$B ~:=~ \frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}3 & 2 & 2 & 3 &  \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & & \\ & 1 & & & \\ & & 1 & & \\ & & & 1 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$

Suppose you have $w \in L_3$, then $wl$ is in $L_2$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ (in case $l = T$), in $L_4$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ (in case $l = N$) and in $L_1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ (in case $l = I$ or $l = P$). This corresponds to the third column of $B$. The other columns are constructed likewise.

What we have done here is constructed the transition matrix of a Markov chain with $5$ states. Each entry $b_{ji}$ of $B$ corresponds to the probability of going from state $L_i$ to state $L_j$ after adding a random letter.

Now consider what happens when we add 15 random letters $l_1, \ldots, l_{15}$ to the empty word $\epsilon$. We know that $S(\epsilon) = s_1$, and now we know that $S(\epsilon l_1\cdots l_{15}) = B^{15}S(\epsilon) = B^{15}s_1$. Now the probability that $\epsilon l_1\cdots l_{15}$ contains $TINT$ is exactly the fifth entry of $S(\epsilon l_1\cdots l_{15})$, which is $s_5^\top B^{15}s_1$, which is the bottom left entry of $B^{15}$. The bottom left entry corresponds to the probability of going from state $L_1$ to state $L_5$ after adding 15 random letters.

> The probability that a randomly chosen 15-letter word $W \in A^{15}$ contains the substring $TINT$ is exactly the bottom left entry of $B^{15}$.

Wolfram Alpha says this number is exactly

$$\frac{49167017}{1073741824}.$$

The probability that $W$ does *not* contain $TINT$ is therefore

$$ 1 - \frac{49167017}{1073741824} = \frac{1024574807}{1073741824}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The following Python script confirms the answer given by @McFry:

```
LENGTH = 15
LETTERS = 'PTIN'
SEQUENCE = 'TINT'

def func(word):
    if len(word) < LENGTH:
        return sum(func(word+letter) for letter in LETTERS)
    else:
        return SEQUENCE not in word

count = func('')
total = len(LETTERS)**LENGTH
print '{}/{}={}%'.format(count,total,100.0*count/total)
```

The output is $1024574807/1073741824\approx95.42\%$.

Answer (score 2):

If "TINT" occurs in $k\gt0$ particular positions and there are $j$ overlaps between them, there are $\binom{k-1}j$ ways to choose the overlaps, $\binom{15-3k}{15-4k+j}$ ways to choose the positions and $4^{15-4k+j}$ ways to choose the remaining letters. Thus by inclusion-exclusion the desired probability is

$$
1+\sum_{k=1}^4(-1)^k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}j\binom{15-3k}{15-4k+j}4^{j-4k}=\frac{1024574807}{1073741824}\approx95.42\%\;.
$$

Comment: I may be mistaken, but this expression may need some adjustment in the case $k=4$. (I changed the exponent of 4 in the last line, but feel free to change it back if I did so incorrectly.)

Comment: @user84413: I believe the exponent was correct; I changed it back. In the text I count the number of words; the equation gives the probability, which is the number of words divided by the total number of words, i.e. $4^{15}$. As regards the case $k=4$, I suspect you mean the case $k=4$, $j=0$ that can't actually occur. No adjustment is needed for this since the corresponding binomial coefficient $\binom3{-1}$ is $0$. (But thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this for me, and I apologize for my "correction".

Comment: Thank you -- this was a very helpful answer, and probably the simplest computationally.